# QlikSense - retrieving row values outside of the current filter selection

Tags: qliksense

I'm trying to create an expression that will retrieve values outside of the user's selection, and at a certain level. My fact table is stacked with multiple fact tables, an example of the data model below:

| Tablename | Country | State | Sales | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | US | California | 100 | null |
| Sales | US | California | 200 | null |
| Sales | US | New York | 200 | null |
| Target | US | null | null | 500 |
| Sales | CA | Toronto | 100 | null |
| Sales | CA | Toronto | 200 | null |
| Sales | CA | Vancouver | 200 | null |
| Target | CA | null | null | 500 |

Sales are at a state/city level, whereas targets are at Country level. The users will select 1 state/city and put it against the country's target to see its contribution. For California, it will be 300 / 500 = 60%.

However since the users will filter by state/city, any target values will return 0.

I'm assuming p() needs to be used somewhere (since the relationship of sales and target are by the country value and not by association) but how do I achieve this via set analysis?

Also, what is the proper term used here where the Sales and Target rows have a relationship due to a common column value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working with [set analysis](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-analysis-expressions.htm), the [`Aggr()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/aggr.htm), and the [`total` keyword](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/define-aggregation-scope.htm). This expression works for me:

```
=Sum(Sales) / Sum(total <[Country]> Aggr(Sum({1} [Target]), [Country]))
```

The denominator in that expression broken out:

```
Sum(total <[Country]> Aggr(Sum({1} [Target]), [Country]))
      ^        ^       ^        ^
      3.       4.      2.       1.
```

1. Here we are summing up the `[Target]` field. We want to ignore users' selections for this part of the expression so we use the [set identifier](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-identifiers.htm) `{1}`.
2. We put that `Sum()` function inside an `Aggr()` function so that we can aggregate or group the `Sum()` on the `[Country]` field.
3. Since the `Aggr()` gave us a summed target value for each country, we now want to `Sum()` those values but give the `total` amount across all dimensions.
4. We can specify a dimension for `total` to ignore, in this case we chose the `[Country]` field so that we can see summed values rolled up to Country but not State/City.

Comment: Thanks! I got the answer myself using Aggr() as well too. However is it possible to solve this using p()?

Comment: I don't think this is a good use case for the `P()` set function because that basically is just a way to say "sum of [Field A] where [Field B] has possible values based on some expression," which is not what you want. What you want is "sum of [Field A] grouped and totaled on [Field B]." You aren't trying to "modify the set" besides using `{1}` to ignore user selections.